# make a textView scale horizontally as text accumulates

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitextview

I am trying to make a textView frame scale horizontally as text accumulates. I am using the code blow to try to make this happen. The frame scales vertically as expected, but the size seems to be locked horizontally.

```
 [myTextView setFrame:CGRectMake(myTextView.frame.origin.x, myTextView.frame.origin.y, myTextView.contentSize.width, myTextView.contentSize.height)];
```

[Here is the project](http://owolf.net/uploads/StackOverflow/TextViewTester.zip) (27K) if anyone wants to take a look.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: as per my understanding... you need to resize the content size too.... [myTextView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(myTextView.contentSize.width+10, myTextView.contentSize.height+10)];

Comment: is it works for u means update me ASAP...

Comment: i think @prince answer is nice it will suit for u try it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement UITextView delegate in .h file this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextViewDelegate>
```

If yourTextView added from xib then bind delegate with fileowner otherwise in ViewDidLoad add this line:

```
yourTextView.delegate = self;
```

---

Use textView's delegate for your requirement:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
   CGSize maximumSize = CGSizeMake(2000,40); //specify height of textView  and maximum width for text to fit in height of textView as u want text horizontally
   CGSize *txtSize = [textView.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16] constrainedToSize:maximumSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap]; //calulate size of text by specifying font here
   //Add UIViewAnimation here if needed
   [textView setFrame:CGRectMake(textView.frame.origin.x,textView.frame.origin.y,txtSize.width+10,txtSize.height+10)]; // change accordingly
   return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is here at [notes-app](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/03/stuff-you-learn-from-reverse-engineering-notes-app/).